# How to get data from table related through pivot table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, eloquent-relationship

I have 4 tables: countries, activities, country_activities and packages.
countries and activities are related through pivot table country_activity, and packages is related to country_activity.
Now, How do I eager load all packages related to each activity in a country?

```
class Country extends Model
{
    public function activities() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity','country_activities')->using('App\Models\CountryActivity')->as('country_activities');
    }
}

class Activity extends Model
{
    public function countries() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Country','country_activities')->using('App\Models\CountryActivity')->as('country_activities');
    }
}

class Package extends Model
{
    public function country_activities() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\CountryActivity');
    }
}

class CountryActivity extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'country_activities';

    public function packages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Package');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in a project i worked on. I'm not sure it will work but it's worth the shot:

```
$country = Country::find(1);
$country->activities = $contry->activities()->get()->each(function ($i, $k){
    $i->packages = $i->pivot->packages;
    //$i->makeHidden('pivot'); -> This is useful if you want to hide the pivot table
});
var_dump($country);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, this worked for me.

```
   class Country extends Model
   {
        public function activities() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity','country_activities')->using('App\Models\CountryActivity')->withPivot(['id'])->as('country_activities');
   }
```

Now, In my controller, I do this

```
    $country = Country::with(['activities'=> function($q) {$q->where('name','Trekking');}])->where('name','Nepal')->first(['id','name']);
    $country->activities->map(function ($i){
        $i->country_activities->load('packages');
        return $i;
    });
```